# How do I get/Scrape the data from <font> tag in html

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy, web-crawler

site Link: https://www.jobup.ch/en/new-vacancies/

Hi guys I am working on the above job site from where I want to scrap jobs data, but the job URL is in the  tag, I have tried a different method to scrap but it does not work for me,
method 1:

```
jobs_soup.find_all('div', {'class':'Div-sc-1cpunnt-0'}).find('font').find('a', href = True)
```

Method-2:

```
response.xpath("//div[@class = 'Div-sc-1cpunnt-0']/font/a")
```

I have tried this both ways but it won't work,
If anyone help me It will be very helpful for, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code is an example how to grab all information from each job listing.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url='https://www.jobup.ch/en/new-vacancies/'
req=requests.get(url)

soup =BeautifulSoup(req.content,'lxml')

for job in soup.select('div.uitpo main ul li div'):
    job_title_link = job.select_one("a[href*='/en/jobs']").get('href')
    print('https://www.jobup.ch' + job_title_link)
```

**Output:**

```
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/4cfa660d-94d3-4ed7-9d8a-76d1ed652ede/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/f61d3652-6973-48f6-bf95-46bfa1898a80/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/62c4a3c3-a811-4093-a682-d7a65b26d803/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/6fba16e2-48ab-4ea0-91d4-e1f78f89e4f1/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/5d2dd694-cb3e-4891-841b-cae56859e7d6/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/19af616a-eee5-42ca-ae80-6964ec2628a0/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/d9bc7165-9196-457c-b110-aa6d5ba5e99a/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/89a4ef10-f0b5-4828-8356-1d9d0e4af55b/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/6a67f2be-2935-45bb-a162-08cbf2ee4536/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/d72edd47-286f-4722-a2ed-05401f4ce292/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/db818b93-e986-41b6-9b69-6ba09b7bd81f/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/8ad48b11-6c92-4244-ae86-0d540ffbd725/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/05b9cf89-f106-422d-b775-357363f2ffde/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/66351c42-f59d-4878-a7fa-611a505258b5/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/cd6d23a3-9686-4e02-a70a-c4cf0efd20e4/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/11854e3f-6444-43ba-855c-11134887ec21/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/b2625f9a-d172-45fd-9001-cb8d0902c790/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/6ef041ed-874c-4185-8f04-ee6c6531394e/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/d1ae8471-1f80-4ff4-b06b-0f6187d91b5c/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/685dbb62-c716-4ba6-80d4-36f6ac2a5875/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/882123ba-93d7-49b2-aff3-84890b8cf4c5/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/2ff77192-9383-4234-9457-276568f2c37c/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/1ddee9b6-b6f1-4877-8ec9-ca1a89a49146/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/e0ac036f-3689-4701-a688-1d04d054049b/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/4d0ebf2b-c4a4-4748-9296-0b8079573442/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/fffad652-8eee-4ccc-9200-7a40aacbff20/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/853433ad-91ac-40d3-91c9-45289a2b5429/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/2afc8f58-0226-4b31-92a0-f4cc25269601/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/ec4416e5-6467-4a71-9743-b72f86073b48/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/ae20d070-e893-4834-8f05-8a54de16796d/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/8124e6d8-e5a7-4df4-889a-b6119e47e39e/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/0f4f41f8-7102-4239-a19f-2ef8b8c07297/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/fb9d9f01-3844-4f92-9849-0c3287bd7d9c/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/3ee1874c-666a-4622-808e-289841533790/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/fde1a7c1-cf57-4286-bf02-f69f71a359b4/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/80f0f3a0-987a-4dea-9c49-bef4e6ec52fc/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/cd5dfab3-16bf-4847-9be8-63f2b9461330/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/883ab739-f2e3-48c4-bd25-37f6ac079c73/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/ee39a23c-45e0-45b6-94c6-dc2a0121aee8/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/c29f0412-991e-43b1-a561-67fef254a2ba/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/c2ceed2b-59b9-497e-961a-f15cac51777e/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/91dc81e8-8421-47eb-bfd4-bb0df5782178/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/e9efee61-aa99-4bc0-9652-e0c5fd449f4d/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/0acff3d5-6aca-4b47-82ab-6905b7ee1b56/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/96105806-b17e-469f-8229-1882a92c07ca/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/8654c61e-c4bd-40bb-9ea5-63ce20139fed/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/2ec6a6c2-b70c-4260-aeee-0983cb3a4680/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/6be10f89-ffa6-41db-b5b6-cd0bbc3fa86d/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/e691225e-4727-4c76-8591-6d50f191913d/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/1318fbc8-3a4c-429d-a0aa-5ff890cfc0e7/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/d0ad3029-49c7-4075-820a-81dc75a124f8/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/f4883b98-546d-40e1-b380-7b93870bbb0d/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/788dbd31-c41a-4db2-8dd1-ea540ec89c64/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/07c4b518-43c7-46b5-bf71-6bb23c912a9f/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/8da6ff9b-73f5-433e-8f2b-63650642c2ce/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/bc1390b2-f155-41d4-8c80-83cb45277764/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/a7b62f1a-3446-45fb-b7ae-4e0295c5d1ca/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/1bba98f3-3959-4c59-a104-57f9f273e1ed/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/8201c8db-864a-49c8-8155-80897cf1b25b/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/831aa7c8-b273-4920-9dac-c5aac538ed19/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/9a2f3962-009b-4aec-8330-5b17c5e82a1c/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/0d391cc4-25ff-460f-a3e6-91e1daaaf96f/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/df97876e-6da6-4041-a3d1-ad2ca044fb26/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/cba05de6-ec5c-4f4c-9705-8887964b8a07/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/a77f4df4-c72e-4e9d-a393-d6d84ce0bd96/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/a1a224b8-0b89-4f14-a51f-b7c9c54a9684/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/b08286cc-7723-49f0-90ec-f4f9c8415ca4/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/7a7b15f1-6429-4321-bcdf-213aed05fbbf/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/22c85ecd-3c67-41cf-a16a-df8a34fa20e3/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/ab7ae037-6744-46a0-9d27-a628d84fffb0/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/365f2729-859e-4c9a-9331-7596b1c58b9b/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/0e900913-2b54-4b7b-89c2-7703b4ddef55/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/488ee17c-89c6-4242-98da-778a55387aa3/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/9a1982be-16e7-48a8-964b-3c874ca3d161/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/502a37b3-5a7c-412f-b151-58303677a846/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/db2f45b7-0128-4aa8-a657-8917d5972a4e/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/67317ad4-87c2-4f82-916b-815400cbf690/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/e15b10ff-47bd-43bd-b451-4c6e038b91f9/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/0ee7abaa-1199-412c-a390-f82d18096ace/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/3c4eea1f-1011-4745-9f51-30b3bfb90bf5/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/14ab0d55-f78a-4705-83f3-f77e379babbb/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/9d47bdd6-2374-4470-acfd-6b4d6cea349d/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/dc3f682a-9d1f-419e-9cbf-34a0c939cb32/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/150a4fe9-7a89-43b9-bf9c-a2ee5d3841a6/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/a227345c-1837-4c5d-8985-61f783f7e840/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/2f1f4c4a-454b-4c49-95ca-3dc3f6b8e8f0/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/f6b76a49-61c7-4f90-9643-63cf9da6668f/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/c031570c-b397-4eff-bc7f-a3076a64f994/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/050ac45c-c415-418b-8bd5-09f828c368d2/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/8325982d-4e87-42c9-b44a-ad932e9f7b6f/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/86d671b0-2abe-432f-bdce-40a610ea657e/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/e0277605-f012-4988-acf6-6699400e96a2/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/06cc8f9a-bfff-479b-ad6d-3ed59cadcea7/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/45f40e01-0a07-4146-9fb2-b680c497642c/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/e5b68d1b-ca78-4138-bb87-8ec5ffc7f3c6/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/bdc09d81-b718-40f4-b448-a41fe6bee625/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/cf6be9da-6976-4f1e-b66a-5bc9ca7c67ae/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/62997ad1-01c9-4809-9934-1e5501c47144/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/f792fe99-ac50-4430-a4fe-87351663ac6c/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/4ff3d031-0d1c-45f3-a24d-938fee7fabb8/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/629c0dfb-1310-482e-9dbb-9a8544fbffe5/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/60160a00-7630-422c-a4ad-984234084eab/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/2d9a2e51-d17e-4cf9-bf88-51f5d56a7b1e/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/e4802f91-7ba9-4860-bcef-926ceeabe1e0/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/e126e8c2-2754-47ff-bde6-e6ca41bb24d7/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/ceaa2770-05af-46ee-ae69-7537c293ca40/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/0fd9d640-4150-461e-b462-4a0ae3f34e37/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/e3358487-b02f-4a73-807d-fd62129ce606/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/d4321da1-a657-491b-a6aa-cf85aa9bb8ea/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/304464c8-897e-4354-8726-86e74d9b7327/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/318e20ab-d451-4903-a898-14f9a1b81675/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/46b05666-2c02-4c98-8975-8c852a257abf/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/730a0f54-78ff-45b2-81fa-404aff2bf5ee/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/2e502233-42c3-4807-9e17-eba929b005d8/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/85548801-63ca-4eef-844f-653dfdbe674b/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/8c32dc52-9f58-4d5d-b602-9dc09cdff67f/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/327990ff-c54e-41ae-b3fb-984d7ffe44cf/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/c6c0343c-9a46-49fb-9ea3-9eac236ed5a7/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/e1aed853-f5a8-4557-b024-8e0428cbd82f/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/b90c5af2-9aaf-49e8-9fe0-3a463a472bb1/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/247a03a9-8ef7-4c87-83a7-8a672dcb61b4/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/a74b16b0-3d32-440d-b166-6aee2f3d5e04/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/98164069-6389-4104-9930-936d3e3b3cfb/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/67c70109-9e9c-482e-933e-6a088ceaf69d/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/9d337cd5-adfd-41a3-9de9-86a8ac4af56c/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/4affc1be-1856-4bc6-845f-3bcb2c504d66/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/139694ea-409b-4673-a8df-6428b0d1084c/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/5c64a03c-d145-48b0-8f38-f6b19f518d88/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/12213dbb-cc2e-46cc-bf7e-19979e761ec5/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/3b21a19e-0533-48ea-b0d6-74bdd1bfbf7f/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/ca1fa6fe-ec8d-4621-87ee-c0e0c2da36c4/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/c5976458-4b25-4cf2-af20-c94efc2b36e4/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/4f24aaa1-43f3-4fe0-bd79-bbb57538baf8/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/20cd700d-ea87-46a9-8020-c4c073bcadd9/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/581df624-3ba4-4509-bd0c-8c003c51d00d/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/6e78c3ba-02fa-4ff9-9415-1c73cdbe898d/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/7e58ff0b-875a-4681-8fc2-c063809bd61b/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/427e9b55-2cba-48cf-a31b-0abcc62333c7/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/6d7f1c81-9140-4d06-93de-9f5f085d35a8/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/dc296dad-f924-4b15-993f-b37b88915eec/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/08f1c811-76d7-4187-a558-3ad297fa3cf7/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/36c5be6c-1919-4959-b5d2-7c45ef0d6271/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/a9a2f942-dbc5-4eab-ae60-aafb9172f8e4/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/47855893-cbea-46df-94ae-00afed9c2d05/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/8a127ac8-c4a6-434f-8911-a8d2853fde77/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/4eaa2dee-54d7-4fb4-9582-663684602b24/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/8fc69b88-bf50-49a8-889d-b0f2f6a89ddb/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/80ded82d-5ee4-44c0-bc3d-102b1561077a/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/939132e8-2602-47a5-b54f-162767fcbb18/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/1f871b71-87c4-4193-9260-bc6389a2d517/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/d3bb6698-5b50-45dd-a2db-feb679344bd1/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/3e6be754-c585-4719-b656-e8f5f592cb19/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/12f0ca88-aca6-49a3-a8b3-e7366518cacd/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/7445ca46-d1e9-40c8-a58f-5d5e1129d981/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/47c612c3-025a-4d05-834f-6094c0d2fd5f/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/b597f092-fbac-474c-84c5-70c3d8df051e/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/71a08389-97b6-4eab-a627-2d2f2a67b470/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/657c7806-6fb2-4732-9f1f-afb75769682c/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/2253a3b2-f787-4a02-bd31-b50c6bf89943/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/b714f326-5c04-4e11-9bf1-afe2e6b12622/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/24e6e56a-c032-4f3d-a3f1-64d6c3e4d3d2/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/d107d840-8b2a-4d75-b65d-aff61a1a06b5/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/9d49645a-57ce-4f1e-b597-481259760663/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/a64edc4f-bf18-40bd-b467-2922512bd29c/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/325f30c5-2306-4f90-92c3-df7ecdc49ee4/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/804ea3bd-c6ea-4906-bc94-2f1c5b8ddf05/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/fb1f9890-fd3e-488c-b4ce-289672cd5f58/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/9bd6867c-049c-406a-90ef-a3e678dda17f/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/2a62d90c-6040-4443-a9c7-37d3f06809a3/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/73cd107b-bff9-4abc-a908-9b59c205bc04/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/4c6972a0-67eb-4948-bb69-b600e01fefcc/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/54c3c219-e7c9-4f83-bd4e-137420b01d4a/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/0d399ccf-02c0-488e-bfc1-d5b4ecca5f7b/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/019903ee-e0de-47b4-a262-a9640aeb67fc/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/a04280a1-13e6-432a-abe2-314f9d471119/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/41d19916-b867-4057-8ef6-78176be416bf/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/eb887d05-f6b6-48c4-9242-c610994223c6/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/e14deaa9-7377-450b-ae5a-5a4519838038/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/b8ec4b73-f1b3-4552-95e4-82d02df2eb0c/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/7bef274c-f25d-405a-8f7e-cdb55ecc1efb/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/385e096f-bf48-4206-a388-0362ea48bdb0/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/80efa576-633b-467c-a9a0-be7311a044c1/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/fed75920-cc76-49b0-8d71-1f95fffa41f8/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/3206e757-9a97-4b24-822e-c06934e0a7c3/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/5af6787a-8540-4425-97c5-dfdd75b38133/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/fbf94352-e077-4823-924c-63634f88cca0/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/6cca0d74-d4b3-4685-b982-2d8f85a6e2e6/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/50f26012-56f5-47d1-95e8-2719983b0d5e/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/3eb3aedf-1b72-4358-99a4-d650632294fb/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/a3de53e1-0d61-4eb5-81cb-cd44244881a7/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/514d1b7b-f09d-473f-81bc-355e8e6e8db6/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/779a3a66-598d-4332-a859-ad64655807b5/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/0647ec09-90c9-41d9-8fab-83a030f2eccf/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/e03e94ca-89f2-4660-bf1c-ac4f00d184a8/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/7b672599-ad63-4c74-a744-7b5dee55879d/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/fe61acb8-9f7d-4708-bee2-e5bcfa844bf7/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/72839dbd-ea73-4156-9af8-147fd30b9a7a/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/986789af-3146-490e-9577-581ad82a97a3/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/e962857d-52ad-45eb-a6cc-40f8aba51017/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/f86723ef-7df9-4468-bebb-5eb776ec243c/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/e29cfdfe-07c2-4c97-bf5d-44ce39b85a41/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/cf9ea7da-dd49-404e-bf1f-7b25e94b221a/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/fd0e67e6-b476-4a0a-a5c8-7df022346879/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/e731a88d-6665-4065-b7cc-fb8b94ff4c5a/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/82f7fad3-1b4f-42b3-822e-d0039753d256/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/85d9806e-e044-40ed-99c6-dd64f257ca50/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/9e622091-ab24-4425-b128-be43d043d036/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/3e1e87b1-7f3a-488d-a482-89b55b9a63cf/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/433263b1-73b7-4b92-b061-9a8663d8123a/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/a5e8c105-4566-4db6-ada6-5df28d7e5701/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/a4087106-affc-4220-8f0f-ed428cc23405/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/a1f8ba2c-db9f-4d7f-bacc-7968812ce7ed/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/3af9d329-6263-403d-9744-b798fdb93dc3/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/04ea8f52-785e-4b26-b036-1482af0177ef/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/5e34e8b9-32e5-4e1a-bcb8-1949df47d957/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/fde5c3e3-e09c-4508-8f27-bf058f664872/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/9719ac32-8291-42cd-a343-a370217f95b0/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/ddfa2b60-77b4-4341-8959-9b87356968e9/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/13d0e658-a222-46bd-9634-a43ab0b8a1d4/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/9a9fb24b-7474-4d18-87b6-ae7dfcb18436/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/4d223b8d-ee4f-4c06-b030-6dfd516460f1/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/7f28f10d-d0ef-4045-bb9d-2dbb13323a60/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/0b0f65aa-a205-4f30-ab31-065a5d6805b3/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/27e3344e-4f1c-488c-a431-38065458449d/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/597a420e-ea72-42fc-8a5a-d16f5fe8222d/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/bff7ce28-9415-4c4d-b987-52088d635ef1/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/f7c94cc2-b8c2-4507-9371-e7a5d7360d07/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/c34eb004-1131-41aa-a018-93e2b40786d7/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/f0285b1d-6035-4378-999e-eccef47ce0ec/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/9c9b73a1-ea3a-4ca4-84cd-f93c9a3361d8/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/f468773a-8f87-4fdb-a6fa-85b8015a9b56/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/19bb20d4-9eb4-4dfc-be78-8b0c0c49488e/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/9b138180-cf38-4cdb-b562-5f47c5af2c75/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/9042bf6d-57e9-43ba-b598-184b97de62cf/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/0b88fa7d-be3c-4efe-8ee4-2fa11cbc3702/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/707ca130-b31d-4cbb-827b-169c31ab62c1/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/69de9d13-c82d-4de4-8025-34993f493496/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/28d3683c-6198-4473-8a74-a87c15d8ec8f/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/e77892ce-102d-47de-b5f0-ec5212c891b3/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/0efa773b-933e-4710-ba7a-eccd261a1a17/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/7f47a250-446f-461f-9d6f-5d375426af5f/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/377be279-0236-4805-9810-2f42da9b8252/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/dab1325e-5dc3-4946-ac61-512542c73fdf/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/49d109f9-160f-4bc3-8540-5f3db656ed93/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/401175a7-ad04-481b-af16-ed25e0344814/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/21b29bb5-91c0-4b3f-8c6f-fcc601e4fadc/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/cf36774a-3cc5-4f2b-a3b9-71d9303d0e49/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/571d2145-4c00-4ebc-84f8-d0815b8ff34e/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/fb34918f-f8a4-41e6-8fca-9a55d853e098/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/36ac3395-6019-4acf-bdda-4baec05c9223/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/5dc5d598-3d42-4049-b8cf-02118ad845e6/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/bf2b5162-10e6-463f-8984-9697b4599228/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/5c73390a-1b8a-42bd-9b36-bc37655bc75b/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/a183be76-e8c4-4166-b3f6-ff17e3d15ee2/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/7c9dd4bc-6b9f-4ffa-9e87-03448c24ab24/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/278bd580-41b5-44ab-92b0-73d45d46a222/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/f1e41fb7-bddc-4c4e-9cb1-e66370a89118/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/36484c7e-a98b-4f80-a135-936ac69caef7/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/2447adb0-922f-4eac-866d-fc74f0747ecf/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/02d47402-2fc7-4a64-8f9b-3d5affa59370/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/2b5d324f-7b9d-465a-85a8-a1ee21cd477a/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/31d2563e-c91c-425d-b1c6-a4e357ee3c1a/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/ad836b1c-d784-4dd3-8c40-231e699518dd/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/c99e9614-3f75-45ab-b6f8-3e640a739062/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/273dcf4c-53ff-4614-95bd-4e8347a9db70/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/d3e3b241-f678-473c-baf0-14b55eb79991/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/a310020f-f6d5-4315-ad6b-a1f76e419efd/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/69f49c3a-77ce-4a4f-a255-936600c79d6a/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/ccbc7bdf-5aa1-4190-82e0-fa563c92a63d/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/027a660d-c034-47e6-9a08-9cded5a7ced5/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/b4bae266-827f-4678-aeac-1a74e4c18845/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/83abb5ed-e3a4-44f4-8395-dd0ab804570e/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/e97373d8-ca29-420f-9fa1-bb471adfdb5e/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/1ac275f5-0138-4416-a9c9-6bc153a430de/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/0f6ee992-b012-486a-994c-69e452e7f148/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/9966e178-5051-47f8-98b2-ea37bd765a5d/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/da890d44-8b3b-45b8-98d2-bd740fbd0d99/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/c800966b-bd2c-454e-bdac-7c945f69c961/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/95cdf1ef-7829-4b59-a958-9242c2472ed8/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/6055213e-082b-4b47-93b3-e0c4f5afc9c5/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/49a2a454-1c40-4900-a91f-a46febc3184b/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/edcdf059-191e-4899-b0fc-2e45d6540aef/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/be599485-3b9d-4446-bdfa-12e6893a088e/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/ef1e6872-77d6-4e5a-a51b-2844b97c058b/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/81c916c6-d958-4ce7-98e6-dd510aaa2f75/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/eecbfb7b-5448-4c2e-9136-18856eab2d76/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/503a7519-7048-4cea-aa19-b24ee5959acf/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/60172683-6d33-47c2-904f-9ba21ec44702/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/7261b875-6cb6-454d-bab1-15a191a2c42e/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/4f3d2c75-330c-4f9e-b26a-82544d9cc723/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/83e87b98-d158-4935-b688-ce4ab61e7877/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/86b81216-07d5-40df-a858-c0dc899bffc4/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/9178423b-a069-44cf-a6e5-dc4c427a74e9/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/71005a96-ed8e-4243-bd28-6c9215b767f0/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/524d6443-29f1-4b00-be1a-0829bb197c44/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/02027a8e-bfef-466d-aff1-121546458ad9/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/f3c5890f-487d-4932-9748-b781f665c9a2/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/edccab6b-b9af-4550-9f6c-5df76d86f5cc/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/3b9d5faa-7c28-4f12-8071-ceba7c215e36/
https://www.jobup.ch/en/jobs/detail/5e1dd033-b4bf-482a-adc6-0a4284c7cebb/
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have time to test it, but I believe this will work

```
jobs_soup.find_all('a[href^="/en/jobs/"]')
```

What this is doing is:

Finding all a tags that have an href starting with /en/jobs/.

Comment: Thank You for your response, I also try this but nothing worked

Comment: I suggest you have a look at the what the jobs_soup is then, make sure it contains the actual website content and you are not getting blocked and/or some elements require JS to be loaded.